# Creating constructors with unknown typed arguments

Tags: c#

I'm making a class

```
class token
{
    public string name; //Known Type
    public ?????? value; //Unknown Type until runtime
    public token(string name, ????? value)
    {
        self.name = name;
        self.value = value;
    }
}
```

What would the correct type(?) of value be to allow data of any type to be input as an argument to the constructor when the class is instantiated?

Comment: Are you looking for *generics*? `class token<T> {... public T value... public token(string name, T value)...}`

Comment: `self` should be `this` in C#. You're probably looking for `object` or, as mentioned, generics.

Comment: Describe more what you mean by "not known until runtime". What determined what the type is? What do you expect to be able to _do_ with the object if you don't know it's type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for generics ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics)):

```
class token<T>
{
    public string name; //Known Type
    public T value; //Unknown Type until runtime
    public token(string name, T value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myToken = new token<string>("Name", "Value");
```

In response to the comment below: This is how you could create the type dynamically at runtime. Please note that `Activator.CreateInstance` can be rather slow so you would want to avoid calling it inside of a loop.

```
var someDynamicType = typeof(string);
var someDynamicValue = "Value";

var type = typeof(token<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string));
var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type, "Name", someDynamicValue);
```

Comment: Nitpick: most of the time, using generics like this isn't really "unknown until runtime", it's really "each implementation chooses they generic arguments, but those generic arguments _are_ known at compile time." The only exception to this is by using Reflection. In this post, it's known at compile time that the `myToken` variable uses the `token` type, which a generic argument `string`. But yes, the argument can be made that "the code in the class itself doesn't know what the generic argument is until you run it".